# Converting View from Landscape to Portrait?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I have already developed the app for Landscape mode,now the client is asking to build in both Landscape and Portrait mode.

How can i convert landscape View to portrait View?

Now i am using this code for Landscape View:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{

 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

 }
```

Please help me....

Advance Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, to support all orientations just return `YES` to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
    //Or to support all but portrait upside down
    return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use autoresizing masks. They are simple but pretty powerful in a majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

NSPostWhenIdle is right. You just have to return yes shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. That way you can have support for all orientations. Have a look at resizing properties through XIB. that will also make your work easy.